# mysql optimization - basic query (withoug joins) for displaying items with pagination

Tags: mysql, database

I am trying to speed up the sql queries in a webpage. The situation is

(a) First query the total number of items with a query like

```
select count(1) from table_name where
column_A = 2
*and column_B = 5 --(this parameter can be be optional)
and column_C = 0 --(this parameter can be optional)
```

(b) Then show the first 10 items with a query like

```
 select list_of_columns from table_name where
 column_A = 2 
 and column_B = 5 --(this parameter can be be optional)
 and column_C = 0 --(this parameter can be be optional)
 order by primary_key_column desc limit 0,10
```

All columns mentioned are integer type. No index in any column as of now except for the primary_key_column which is the primary key.

I have been going through indexes and similar approaches to see if this situation can be improved in terms of performance.

My thoughts are

> (1) Use single query instead of two different queries using
>   SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS and FOUND_ROWS()

But with my testing, it seems this does not give any performance improvement as this also queries database two times. Possibly, data needs not be sent between php server and mysql server is the only advantage here. But still, i do not get any performance improvement and sometime this approaches slows down things.

> (2) add indexes

But I am not able to decide on the columns. whether a composite index or independent indexes on the columns in where clause need to be given.

Please help in this.

Note: insert/update is only 10% of the total use and rest 90% are select queries.

Comment: Can options a and c be selected, with b omitted?

Comment: yes it is possible.

Comment: So, try two composite indexes: one on (a,b,c) and one on (a,c) -- or (a,c,b) and (a,b) if the cardinality of b and c is very different

Comment: @Strawberry, whether these composite indexes you mentioned also include the primary_key_column?

Comment: No, the pk column has a cardinality of 1, so there's no point including it in a composite index

Comment: ok. thanks for the help